# Why is the output of the string 'text2' blank?

Tags: c++, string

'text1' is a sentence. I want 'text2' to contain the first word of the sentence in 'text1' (all letters before the first space).

The code gets compiled successfully, but, when executed, nothing gets printed on the screen.

Below is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,k,c;
    bool done=false;
    string text1,text2;
    getline(cin, text1);
    for(i=0; i<text1.size(); i++)
    {
        if(text1[i]==' ' && done==false)
        {
            c=i;
            for(k=0; k<i; k++)
            {
                text2[k]=text1[i-c];
                c--;
            }
            done=true;
        }
        
    }
    cout<<text2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `text2` is empty, and you are accessing it out of bounds with `text2[k]=text1[i-c];`.

Comment: `text2[k]` is undefined behavior, for any value of `k`, due to it being empty. Why not simply `text2 = text1.substr (0, text1.find (' '))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do `text2[k]=text1[i-c]` as text2 is empty, you need to resize it first.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,k,c;
    bool done=false;
    string text1,text2;
    getline(cin, text1);
    for(i=0; i<text1.size(); i++)
    {
        if(text1[i]==' ' && done==false)
        {
            c=i;
            text2.resize(i);
            for(k=0; k<i; k++)
            {
                text2[k]=text1[i-c];
                c--;
            }
            done=true;
        }

    }
    cout<<text2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text2.push_back(text1[i-c])` ([API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)), because indexing into an empty string (which is what `text2` is) with `text2[k]` invokes undefined behavior. That indexing operation doesn't change the length of `text2` (or its contents).